# User error: pattern match failure in 'do' block Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am trying to construct a script that:

1. reads a csv file line by line (lines contain lists)
2. zips these lists together in a particular way
3. outputs a new csv file

So, for an input like this:

```
"[1,2,3]"   "[5,24,3]"  "[1,3,4,5]" "[0,8,6]"
```

The output should be

```
"[1,5,1,0]" "[2,24,3,8]"    "[3,3,4,6]" "[5]"
```

This is what I have so far:

```
import Data.List
import Control.Exception
import System.IO
import System.Environment (getArgs)
-- Task 4, 5, 6
-- This is the zip function that operates differently
multiZipL :: [[a]] -> [[a]]
multiZipL [] = []
multiZipL (pps) = [p | p<- map head (pps)] : multiZipL (nltail (pps))

nltail:: [[a]] -> [[a]]
nltail [] = []
nltail xss = filter (not.null) $ map tail xss
-- splitOn helps out with processing each list separately
splitOn :: Char -> String -> [String]
splitOn c [] = []
splitOn c ls = (takeWhile (/=c) ls) : splitOn' c (dropWhile (/=c) ls)
 where splitOn' c [] = []
       splitOn' c (x:[]) | x==c = [[]]
       splitOn' c (x:xs) | x==c = splitOn c xs
                         | otherwise = []
-- Error handling for improper file
fileMZip :: String -> IO ()
fileMZip fileName = catch (fileMZip' fileName) filehandler 

filehandler :: IOException -> IO ()  
filehandler e = 
  do let err = show (e :: IOException)
     hPutStr stderr ("Warning: Couldn't open input/output file : " ++ err)
     return ()

-- This block does the zipping and the printing to a new file
fileMZip' fileName = 
  do s <- readFile fileName
     let ls = lines(s)
     let sss = map (splitOn ',') ls
     let iss = map (map read) sss :: [[Int]]
     let mss = multiZipL iss
     let oss = map (map show) mss
     let css = intercalate "\n" (map (intercalate ",") oss) 
     writeFile "ziplists.csv" css


main :: IO ()
main = do (fileName : _ ) <- getArgs
          fileMZip fileName
```

I am unsure if the problem is with the filename handling or the fact that I don't give any inputs when I compile the file. Honestly, I am not so sure where I should provide the filenames as inputs.

What I have noticed is that, after compiling it with ghc, the executable crashes with this statement:

```
t4.exe: user error (Pattern match failure in 'do' block at t4.hs:46:11-25)
```

Which corresponds to this block

```hs
main :: IO ()
main = do (fileName : _ ) <- getArgs
          fileMZip fileName
```

Comment: Well, are you providing any arguments when you run the executable?

Comment: Sounds like `getArgs` returned an empty list. Check that you are providing the file name to the executable when you launch it.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you have not passed a file name to your program on the command line.

Also, your program is pretty complicated. I strongly recommend using an existing CSV library. For example, here's what it would look like with [cassava](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cassava):

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LBS
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import Data.Csv
import Data.List
import System.Environment

vtrans :: V.Vector [Int] -> [[Int]]
vtrans = transpose . V.toList

main :: IO ()
main = do
    filename:_ <- getArgs
    LBS.readFile filename >>= \bs -> case decode NoHeader bs of
        Left err -> putStrLn err
        Right v -> LBS.writeFile "ziplists.csv" (encode (vtrans v))
```

Try it out:

```
% cat >test.csv <<EOF
heredoc> 1,2,3
heredoc> 5,24,3
heredoc> 1,3,4,5
heredoc> 0,8,6
heredoc> EOF
% ./transpose-csv test.csv
% cat ziplists.csv
1,5,1,0
2,24,3,8
3,3,4,6
5
```